# Random Images not displaying images

Tags: javascript

```
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                     <!--
                        document.write("<img src =../images/"" + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * 3) + ".jpg\" />");
                        <img src="../images/1.jpg" width="500" height="281" alt=""/>
                     // -->
                 </script>
```

Hey guys, as you can see that the second line in the script code shows where the source of the images are.

I am trying to obtain an image at random and write it.

But it's showing the icon of the image (the small icon which indicates the image hasn't loaded.

Can someone please show me how the coding will go. Thank you.

I'm new to javascript, so sorry for being a "newbie".

Comment: As you can see with syntax highlighting you have an unmatching amount of `"`'s. You also need to put `src` inside quotes.

Comment: document.write("<img src = \"" + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * 2 ) + ".jpg\" />");

Thank you, dream weaver has picked up no errors on this, still, how i can I access my images src folder?

Comment: How to access your images src folder? By placing files in the directory? I don't think I understand..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, you can escape quotes by putting a backslash in front of it. Also, you should not use spaces between your attribute keys and values.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.write("<img src=\"../images/" + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * 3) + ".jpg\" />");
// -->
</script>
```

Comment: http://www.computing.northampton.ac.uk/~13422770/assign1/Main/games.html I have looked at the source code and there is a space between 1 and .jpg. although I see no spaces.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I've updated the answer. I was escaping the wrong quotes.

Comment: Justus! You're a star! I wish there was a way to thank you more! Thank you so much! 
"you can escape quotes by putting a backslash in front of it. Also, you should not use spaces between your attribute keys and values." I will keep this mind! :D

Comment: If it solved your issues, you can accept / upvote the answer. This is how Stack Overflow works: a community driven Q&A.